# OpenERP 6.0.4 XML Domain by Python Context List

Tags: python, xml, dns, odoo

I've been trying to create a domain filter on an XML domain for the past few days with no positive results as yet.

I have a field on my form tied to a function

```
def _return_reviewer_exempt(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):

    dr_obj = self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context)
    for dr in dr_obj:
        id = dr.id
    drre_obj = self.pool.get('drre').search(cr,uid,[('document','=',id)],context=context)
    result = {}
    res = list()
    i = 0
    drre_obj = self.pool.get('drre').browse(cr,uid,drre_obj,context=context)
    for drre in drre_obj:
        #boo = True
        res.append(drre.user.id)
        i += 1
    context["list_users"] = res
    result[id] = i
    return result
```

On the XML side the domain I'm attempting to create is on the field

```
<field name="content_lead_review_id" domain="[('groups_id','=','DRLR'),'|',('id','not in',(context.get('list_users')))]" />
```

When I use a static value in my xml I see results, such as:

```
<field name="content_lead_review_id" domain="[('groups_id','=','DRLR'),'|',('id','not in',('3'))]" />
```

This is leading me to believe that there is something wrong with the way in which the list is being generated within the XML coming from the Python Context. Can you please advise as to where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this, It may be work for you.

```
<field name="content_lead_review_id" domain="[('groups_id','=','DRLR'),'|',('id','not in',str(context.get('list_users')))]" />
```

Comment: I tried that ... also tried:

<field name="content_lead_review_id" domain="[('groups_id','=','DRLR'),'|',('id','not in',map(str, context.get('list_users')))]" />

with no success

Your suggestion produces a "Index out of range" error. My own just doesn't successfully filter out anything.